# Linq: Namespace in code before unknown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

If I have something with a LINQ extension like

```
// Declaration: Code Behind
Protected MyList As IList(Of Object)
// Code Before
MyList.First()
```

in code behind, VS is always complaining something like `'First' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IList {...}`. Everything works though, I just would like to get rid of these annoying errors.

I tried:

```
<%@ Import namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

In my ASPX pages but it didn't help.

I also tried the following, none of which worked:

- Add the namespace in the pages-node of web.config
- `Imports System.Linq` in code behind

P.S.: Resharper doesn't mark it as error, interestingly...

Comment: Have you got the latest version of linq?

Comment: @RyanMcDonough What do you mean? LINQ is part of .Net, it's not some separate library.

Comment: Please paste more of the code. Also, LINQ features change per .net release, since it was in .net 3.5 you could of been attempting to use a feature written for a later version. I was just checking. Again post yoor query.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the query, which is working absolutely fine, really. Any extension method of linq gives me that error for nothing. Posting more code won't do any difference to solve the problem. `MyList.First()`, `MyList.Any()` etc. leads all to the same error (which is not really an error by the end).

Comment: WebForms or MVC? I don't think it matters, but good to know...

Comment: We need the declaration of MyList - I suspect it may not be an IList<T> but just an IList, if you have something declared as a non-generic list Linq doesn't work on it

Comment: @James Ellis-Jones: I added the declaration (which is generic, yes - otherwise the site would throw an Exception if it is only an IList I guess).

Comment: Just a crazy thought, but for some reason it does help once in a while. How about deleting your .suo and .vbproj.user(if it exists) files. This resets some things, and occasionally it's fixed stupid VS issues for me in the past.

Comment: @Joe Enos: Good to know, I deleted these two files. But in that particular case it didn't help.

Comment: @sl3dg3 Is this a Web Application Project or a Web Site?

Comment: @Mike C It is a Web Application

Answer (score 0):

You've probably resolved your problem long ago but, for the next person:

The message you're getting is correct but not helpful: "First" is, in fact, not a member of the List class. First is, however, an extension method that attaches itself to the List class (or any class that implements the IQueryable interface, as the List class does).
Unfortunately, the class containing the First method is in the `System.Linq` namespace and the compiler is unable to find that class unless you provide a namespace directive (Import/using statement) to your code. If you add either of these statements to your code file, your problem should go away:

```
Imports System.LINQ
Using System.LINQ
```

Adding the declaration to your .aspx file won't help, though.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I also added the Using - statement in code behind, without luck. Unresolved until today... but working.

Answer (score -1):

I have test below code using " System.Collections.Generic " namespace and it's working fine...

```
     List<int> intList = new List<int>();
               intList.Add(5);
               intList.Add(10);
               intList.Add(15);
               intList.Add(20);
               intList.Add(25);
               int x = intList.First<int>();
               int y = intList.Last<int>();
```

is this fulfilled your requirement??